# MatplotLib - Grouping Query Results into Multiple Plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a query equivalent to

```
SELECT
     MONTH,
     TEAM,
     COUNT(*)
FROM
    TABLE
```

Which I'm intending to plot the results of using Matplotlib, with separate plots on the same graph for different values of TEAM. The possible values for this field aren't known in advance.

What would be the best way to split the list returned from the cursor so that it's suitable for sending to pyplot?

Answer (score 0):

Here is *a* way to split the list. I don't know if it is the "best way to split the list."

```
def display(conn):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('select month, team, count(*) from events group by month, team')
    months = defaultdict(list)
    count = defaultdict(list)
    for row in cur:
        months[row[1]].append(int(row[0]))
        count[row[1]].append(int(row[2]))
    cur.close()
    for k in months:
        pylab.plot(months[k], count[k], label=k)
    pylab.legend()
    pylab.show()
```

---

Complete sample program:

```
import sqlite3
import pylab
from collections import defaultdict

def populate_table(conn):
    with conn:
        conn.execute('create table events (month, team, value)')
        conn.executemany(
            'insert into events values (?,?,?)', (
                (1, 'Bluejays', 98.2),
                (1, 'Redbirds', 42),
                (1, 'Green Eggs and Ham', 1),
                (1, 'Bluejays', 98.2),
                (1, 'Redbirds', 42),
                (1, 'Bluejays', 98.2),
                (1, 'Green Eggs and Ham', 1),
                (2, 'Green Eggs and Ham', 98.2),
                (2, 'Redbirds', 42),
                (2, 'Green Eggs and Ham', 1),
                (2, 'Bluejays', 98.2),
                (2, 'Redbirds', 42),
                (2, 'Bluejays', 98.2),
                (2, 'Green Eggs and Ham', 1),
                (3, 'Green Eggs and Ham', 98.2),
                (3, 'Redbirds', 42),
                (3, 'Green Eggs and Ham', 1),
                (3, 'Bluejays', 98.2),
                (3, 'Redbirds', 42),
                (3, 'Redbirds', 98.2),
                (3, 'Green Eggs and Ham', 1)))

def display(conn):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('select month, team, count(*) from events group by month, team')
    months = defaultdict(list)
    count = defaultdict(list)
    for row in cur:
        months[row[1]].append(int(row[0]))
        count[row[1]].append(int(row[2]))
    cur.close()
    for k in months:
        pylab.plot(months[k], count[k], label=k)
    pylab.legend(loc="lower left")
    pylab.xlim(.5,3.5)
    pylab.xticks(range(1,4))
    pylab.ylim(.5,3.5)
    pylab.yticks(range(1,4))
    pylab.xlabel("Month")
    pylab.ylabel("Events")
    pylab.show()


conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
populate_table(conn)
display(conn)
```

Result:

[image]